# Why does my program not output all my data?

Tags: pascal, output, lazarus

```
program ZZX1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

uses
  crt,
  wincrt,
  {$IFDEF UNIX}{$IFDEF UseCThreads}
  cthreads,
  {$ENDIF}{$ENDIF}
  Classes
  { you can add units after this  };
type
  Masquerader = record
    Name, CountyCode: string;
    Payment: real;
   end;
var
  Applicant: array[1..10] of Masquerader;
  DemList: array[1..10] of string;
  BerList: array[1..10] of string;
  EsqList: array[1..10] of string;
  x:integer;
  Y:integer;
  DemCounter:integer;
  BerCounter:integer;
  EsqCounter:integer;
  DemAmount:real;
  BerAmount:real;
  EsqAmount:real;

 procedure LoadData;
 begin
    clrscr;
X:=0;
DemCounter:=0;
BerCounter:=0;
EsqCounter:=0;
DemAmount:=0;
BerAmount:=0;
EsqAmount:=0;
repeat
X:= x+1;
repeat
write('Enter Your County Code DemM or BerM or EsqM: ');
readln(Applicant[x].CountyCode);
until (Applicant[x].CountyCode= 'DemM') or (Applicant[x].CountyCode= 'BerM') or (Applicant[x].CountyCode= 'EsqM');
If Applicant[x].CountyCode = 'DemM' then
  begin
    write('Enter Your Name: ');
    readln(Applicant[x].Name);
    write('Enter Your Total Payment: ');
    readln(Applicant[x].Payment);
    clrscr;
    DemCounter:= DemCounter + 1;
    DemAmount:= DemAmount + Applicant[x].Payment;
    DemList[DemCounter]:= Applicant[x].Name;
  end;
If Applicant[x].CountyCode = 'BerM' then
  begin
    write('Enter Your Name: ');
    readln(Applicant[x].Name);
    write('Enter Your Total Payment: ');
    readln(Applicant[x].Payment);
    clrscr;
    BerCounter:= BerCounter + 1;
    BerAmount:= BerAmount + Applicant[x].Payment;
    BerList[BerCounter]:= Applicant[x].Name;
  end;
If Applicant[x].CountyCode = 'EsqM' then
  begin
    write('Enter Your Name: ');
    readln(Applicant[x].Name);
    write('Enter Your Total Payment: ');
    readln(Applicant[x].Payment);
    clrscr;
    EsqCounter:= EsqCounter + 1;
    EsqAmount:= EsqAmount + Applicant[x].Payment;
    EsqList[EsqCounter]:= Applicant[x].Name;
  end;
until x=6 ;

 end;

Procedure PrintData;
  begin
    Y:= 0;
    for y := 1 to 6 do
    begin
      writeln('Name: ', Applicant[y].Name);
      writeln('CountyCode: ', Applicant[y].CountyCode);
      writeln('Payment: ', Applicant[y].Payment:0:2);
      writeln;
    end;
    For Y:= 1 to DemCounter do
      begin
        writeln(DemList[Y]);
        writeln(DemCounter,'',' persons are registered in Demerara');
        writeln;
        writeln('DemTotal:$ ', DemAmount:0:2);
      end;
    For Y:= 1 to BerCounter do
      begin
        writeln(BerList[Y]);
        writeln(BerCounter,'',' persons are registered in Berbice');
        writeln;
        writeln('BerTotal:$ ', BerAmount:0:2);
      end;
    For Y:= 1 to EsqCounter do
      begin
        writeln(EsqList[Y]);
        writeln(EsqCounter,'',' persons are registered in Essequibo');
        writeln;
        writeln('EsqTotal:$ ', EsqAmount:0:2);
      end;
 end;
Procedure quit;
  begin
    writeln('Press <Enter> To Quit');
    readln;
  end;

begin
  LoadData;
  PrintData;
  quit;
end.
```

This program currently collects 6 persons and groups them by their countycode, calculating the total amount of persons and money collected by each county.
When I run the program below my expected output is on the screen for a few seconds then it disappears leaving only a piece of the expected output( The end Part). Please assist.

Comment: And remove wincrt. It has no place in a console program, it is for Windows Graph programs.

Answer (score 2):

If there are characters in the keyboard buffer when the program reaches the `readln;` statement in the procedure `quit`, `readln` will read those characters and continue onwards rather than waiting for further input before continuing.

To check this, try adding a character variable as a parameter to `readln` and write the ASCII value of the character out (or check its value in a debugger) to see if there is anything in that variable after the `readln`.

(EDIT)

After further thinking, I wonder if the code like:

```
For Y:= 1 to EsqCounter do
  begin
    writeln(EsqList[Y]);
    writeln(EsqCounter,'',' persons are registered in Essequibo');
    writeln;
    writeln('EsqTotal:$ ', EsqAmount:0:2);
  end;
```

... should actually read something like:

```
For Y:= 1 to EsqCounter do
  begin
    writeln(EsqList[Y]);
  end;
writeln(EsqCounter,'',' persons are registered in Essequibo');
writeln;
writeln('EsqTotal:$ ', EsqAmount:0:2);
```

... because otherwise the same values of `EsqCounter` and `EsqTotal` will be output `EsqCounter` times, which seems unnecessary.

Comment: I've simulated this; twice. Now I can't simulate it anymore. All the other attempts succeeded. Unfortunately, I've stepped with the debugger in a rough way without checking disassembly, but I know it happened when I stepped over the lines in the `PrintData` procedure in the loop with the `DemCounter` iterator, where are just `WriteLn` calls, so I'd say the problem will be somewhere else. While the `WriteLn` was called in a loop, the lines were somehow scrolled up out of the screen buffer. Strange...

Comment: Would you be able to suggest how to simulate this problem ?

Comment: @TLama: Unfortunately, I don't have a running Pascal compiler on my PC at present so I haven't been able to test the code myself. Your comment made me think about the loops, though, and I've edited my answer to suggest taking the bare `writeln` calls out of the loops, along with the counter and total value outputs, which all seem to be repeated unnecessarily.

Comment: Thank you for the editing part. I was so concerned about getting the entire output that i made that stupid mistake. I should note that after the removal of all clrscr the entire output was projected to the screen

Comment: After making a few changes such as the restructuring of the loop as kindly suggested above and the renaming of some variables e.g. `Applicant` is now Reveler and `PrintData` is now PrintRevelerData. Uncertain as to what the exact reason was for the problem stated above I decided to test the code using a different pascal compiler called Dev-Pascal. After implementing the code using this compiler I did not encounter the same problem with screen output that occurred using Lazarus I.D.E. N.B. I stated above that the removal of all `clrscr` projected the entire output. I was clearly mistaken.

Comment: devpascal is merely an IDE, not a compiler. There are two editions, one of which with Free Pascal, the same compiler as Lazarus uses. But Lazarus uses a current one, and dev-pascal one from 2002